# How properly set up remote server through nested tmux sessions

Tags: ssh, server, tmux

I'm trying to set up my remote server so that I can ssh in, start a python process, then detach, logout, and shut down my local computer. I've been able to do this before using nested tmux sessions:

local host - tmux - ssh into remote

remote host - tmux - start python process - detach remote tmux

"exit" from the remote host and close down the remote session.

This was working just fine for me. I can detach the remote session, close down ssh, shut down everything locally, then boot up, relogin via ssh, and then reattach the remote tmux session.

My issue is that now my remote server is in a lab setting (I now run a lab with multiple people, whereas before it was just me). I don't want different users to be logging in when there is a process running. I'm trying to limit people not knowing a server is in use, logging in to start a process, and disrupting (or diverting memory from) a process being run by another user.

My way around this was to setup a generic login user and password that everyone in the lab uses. Then, for that generic user, I edited the /etc/security/limits.conf file to have a maxlogins of 1 for that user. While this works in practice (no other user can log in when one is already logged in), it means I can no longer RE login.

Now I get:
local host -> tmux -> ssh into remote
remote host -> tmux -> start python process -> remote detach
remote host -> exit ssh

local host -> tmux -> ssh into remote:
Too many logins for 'lab2'.

It appears that, with the process still running, the login stays active and I am trying to 'relogin' to an ongoing login session. But since I've set the max to 1, I cannot. Does anyone have any advice for how to fix this?

Thanks!